# Which hosts file is apache using?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up apache virtual hosts on my local machine. Since my file system is kind of a mess, I have several hosts files hanging around. Is there a way to determine which hosts file my apache installation is using?

Answer (score 2):

Use `apachectl -S` to determine which virtual hosts (and their location in files) are in your configuration.

Comment: I guess I'm not explaining myself well enough. I'm looking for the hosts file, not the .conf files.

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with the virtual hosts.  `/etc/hosts`..?

Comment: nevermind, I think I found it `/private/etc/hosts`. I had a hosts file manager that was confusing things.

Comment: Hosts file manager?  That certainly could confuse things.  Why not use DNS instead?

Comment: It was an old setup that a friend at work setup for me. Not sure why he chose it.

Answer (score -2):

```
ps aux | grep catalina
```

Should show the conf files which are being used by the currently running catalina instance.

Comment: Is that just for apache Tomcat? I tried the command and didn't get back any info about my hosts file.

Comment: I am afraid its only for tomcat.